# Rails controller.js.coffee not showing up

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, controller, coffeescript

I just started using Rails.

Inside assets javascripts there's a file (welcome.js.coffee) that says

```
# Place all the behaviors and hooks related to the matching controller here.
# All this logic will automatically be available in application.js.
# You can use CoffeeScript in this file: http://coffeescript.org/
```

I have placed this function just under

```
$(document).ready ->
    alert "Hello World"
```

Inside my application.js file, if I put

```
//= require welcome
```

the alert is showed, otherwise no.

I'm I skipping something or even though the welcome.js.coffee file says that logic will automatically be available in application.js I still have to require the file manually?

Answer (score 0):

Your `application.js` should list

```
//= require_tree .
```

as one of the lines, which requires every other file in the directory tree that that file is in. If this line is missing or required, you will have to add it back or else require files specifically (as you did with `welcome`) for it to work.

Comment: My application.js is listing all this: //= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require backstretch
//= require_tree.

Comment: Is there a space between the `require_tree` and the `.`? If not, add one and see if that works. Everything else is normal.